# Lambda returning "code: 'ResourceNotFoundException"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I wrote a lambda to enable recording from amazon connect call flow but it's returning error: code: 'ResourceNotFoundException

Lambda code:

```
  var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var connect = new AWS.Connect();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var params = {
        ContactId: '$ContactId', /* required */
        InitialContactId: '$InitialContactId', /* required */
        InstanceId: 'ab71a95e-7b8a-46bd-bf37-8145924a7c85', /* required */
        VoiceRecordingConfiguration: { /* required */
          VoiceRecordingTrack: "ALL"
        }
    };
    
        connect.startContactRecording(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            else     console.log(data);           // successful response
          });

    callback(null, event);
    
};
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
    START RequestId: 3c1c71f0-897c-4256-97d4-f1c875c22437 Version: $LATEST
2021-07-13T19:51:50.993Z    3c1c71f0-897c-4256-97d4-f1c875c22437    INFO    ResourceNotFoundException: Resource not found
    at Object.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/rest_json.js:55:8)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12) {
  code: 'ResourceNotFoundException',
  time: 2021-07-13T19:51:50.933Z,
  requestId: 'c6fc6a67-47ec-4ea6-b10d-b8e8cf5f43a6',
  statusCode: 404,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 60.67135195272051
} ResourceNotFoundException: Resource not found
    at Object.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/rest_json.js:55:8)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
END RequestId: 3c1c71f0-897c-4256-97d4-f1c875c22437
```

Could anyone review it and confirm what am I missing?

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe your `InstanceId` does not exist on the lambda function region (or account)

Comment: That's an interesting one. Btw the instance is on us-west-2 so do I need to specify different region than us-east-1? If so...how? Thanks for the help

Comment: `var connect = new AWS.Connect({region: 'us-west-2'});`

Comment: Thanks hoangdv I found it on internet but didn't worked